# Path Error running CakePHP's "cake" console utility in Windows

Tags: shell, cakephp, path, console

A while ago when I started with Cake, I managed to get the console running in my Windows environment, and I have no idea how. I'm now having problems to make it work again in another computer.

This is what I've done in the new machine:

- Downloaded my Cake code from source control (so all the files are *exactly* the same as the computer where it worked, including the configuration files)
- Added PHP and "c:\my_cake_path\cake\console" to the path

If I run "cake OneOfMyShells", either standing on the /app, or in /cake/console directories, I get the following error:

```
Warning: get_object_vars() expects parameter 1 to be object, null given in C:\my_cake_path\cake\libs\model\connection_manager.php on line 199 
Error: Missing Database Connection. Try 'cake bake'
```

"cake Bake", if run normally, when I try to get it to do the DB config ends up throwing another error (which is not that relevant to this)

**However**, if I run: cake bake -app "c:\my_cake_path\app"

Then bake works, I can do the database config, and it writes the DB config file (which is useless at this point, since I already had one)

Then, of course: cake OneOfMyShells -app "c:\my_cake_path\app"

does work perfectly well.

So, everything's working fine, I just need to manually specify the path to "app" every single time, which is very annoying.

How can I get around this? Where is Cake looking for to find the path to app?

Thanks!
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Not much of a difference in the sense you still need to type but you can run cake from the app dir like this: `C:\XXX\project\app> ..\cake\console\cake.bat`

To make it smaller you can put that line on a .bat or just add the `\cake\console` dir the windows path

Comment: That's not really the problem. That part works, and /cake/console is already in the windows path. The problem is taht once cake runs, it apparently can't find the files it needs...

Comment: @DanielMagliola Well, I understood that it worked for you only if called cake giving the app as a paramenter, I had the same exactly problem and solved by running from the /app dir.

Comment: always, always run your shells from the app dir! especially with cake2 - and you will be fine!